# Bitcoin-qt: symbol lookup error: bitcoin-qt: undefined symbol: _ZN12QApplication10commitDataER15QSessionManager

Tags: 16.04, gnome-terminal, qt

Literally have done nothing to Bitcoin-qt.  I will install it, download everything overnight, and then try to restart my computer after installing it all and then I can no longer run `bitcoin-qt` and it gives me this lookup error.

I've literally reinstalled Ubuntu 4 different times this week, I've spent hours googling for anything remotely similar to my issue, and I've even broken my system once trying to fix this issue.  I've redownloaded the Bitcoin Core 4 times as well using 600GB of data. I've even tried both Ubuntu 16.04 and 17.04 and both keep breaking like this.

```
Bitcoin-qt: symbol lookup error: bitcoin-qt: undefined symbol: _ZN12QApplication10commitDataER15QSessionManager
```

I'm literally doing nothing except restarting my computer and I even properly shut down Bitcoin-Qt before I restart and I make sure to `sudo killall bitcoin-qt` and it will tell me every time that there are no processes running.

I've reinstalled my system 4 times and I'm not about to reinstall another Ubuntu copy.  Someone please tell me what is causing this issue because I've spent hours googling and trying literally everything that anyone says and nothing is working.

Answer (score -1):

Because I'm sure anyone using Bitcoin-qt on Ubuntu will inevitably face this issue since I have faced it 4 times without fail in a row:

Go to `/usr/local/lib` and you will find a bunch of `libQt` files there like `libQtCore.so*` and `libQtGui`, etc. Move EVERY `libQt` file out from `/usr/local/lib` and move it into `/usr/`.

For some reason, this will let Bitcoin-qt run again.

Before, clicking on it from the Search menu did nothing, clicking the executable in the `/usr/bin/` folder did nothing, and running `bitcoin-qt` from a terminal window did nothing. Now it works fine again and everything will run.

Solved after 4 reinstallations of Ubuntu, breaking my system once (and losing some code I wrote), and many many hours of googling and trying everything there is.